# Use ST_DWithin on WGS84 geometry data

Tags: postgis, wgs84, osm2pgsql, mercator

I've just used osm2pgsql to import osm data to a PostGIS database, using lat/long option to store it in WGS84 projection. I would like to use ST_DWithin to select nodes close to a random point. When I try that directly on the WGS84 data it returns wrong results but works if I reproject it in Web Mercator. What am i missing to avoid the reprojection?

```
SELECT ST_AsText(way),
       ST_X(ST_AsText(way)) as X,
       ST_Y(ST_AsText(way)) as Y,
       railway
  FROM planet_osm_point
 WHERE railway IS NOT NULL AND
       ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(way, 3785),
                  ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-1.631560, 48.107485), 4326), 3785),
                  500)
 LIMIT 1000;
```

[image: Mercator projection output]

```
SELECT ST_AsText(way),
       ST_X(ST_AsText(way)) as X, 
       ST_Y(ST_AsText(way)) as Y,
       railway
  FROM planet_osm_point 
 WHERE railway IS NOT NULL AND
       ST_DWithin(way, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-1.631560, 48.107485), 4326), 500)
 LIMIT 1000;
```

[image: WGS84 projection output]

As you can see the outputs from WGS84 projection aren't even close to the point I'm lookin at and I can't figure out why when I am using the same geometry type for ST_DWithin. Is there a step I'm missing?
(also I am not showing all of the results here, the Web Mercator projection gets me about 154 results, while WGS84 projection goes beyond 1000)

Comment: Can you try `ST_SetSRID(way, 4326)` ensure it thinks they are in the same CRS?

Comment: On a side note web Mercator is 3857

Comment: Make sure you have a spatial index in place `ON planet_osm_point USING GIST (ST_Transform(way, 3857));`, or, **in conjunction with the correct answer below**, `ON planet_osm_point USING GIST ((way::GEOGRAPHY));` to benefit from index lookup performance!

Comment: Web Mercator should not ever be used for distance or area calculations, as the poles are infinitely far away from the Equator. Even locations close to the Equator have wrong distances, but far away locations have **very wrong** distance/area values.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are using ST_DWithin on GEOMETRY objects with coordinates in WGS84. Therefore, your function call is requesting all features within 500 degrees (i.e., everything on the planet). https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

To calculate the distance in metres, cast the geometries to geography data type:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(way),
       ST_X(ST_AsText(way)) as X, 
       ST_Y(ST_AsText(way)) as Y,
       railway
  FROM planet_osm_point 
 WHERE railway IS NOT NULL AND
       ST_DWithin(way::geography,
                  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-1.631560, 48.107485), 4326)::geography,
                  500)
 LIMIT 1000;
```

This will return slightly different distances compared to when you project to EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) because that projection does not maintain distances to scale. Casting to geography will provide more accurate results by calculating distances using ellipsoid calculations, by default.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, i have used it instead and looked up for some info on difference between geography and geometry type, i would put you as an aswer to my question but i'm not sure how

Comment: @Bad_deepLearner Glad to hear this worked for you. To see how to accept an answer, see [this question on GIS.SE meta](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/how-to-accept-the-answers).